# Using Subversive to move the head back one revision

Tags: eclipse, svn, subversive

Using Eclipse/Subversive I commanded it to delete a branch of mine. Unfortunately it also took the liberty of wiping out my trunk folder. SVN isn't my strong suit so I am trying to figure out how to get Subversive to move it's head back one revision so the trunk/branch that was deleted re-appears again. Anyone have any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [undoing changes](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.branchmerge.basicmerging.html#svn.branchmerge.basicmerging.undo) at the svnbook website. You're looking for a reverse merge. Something like (assuming revision 1234 was where it all went wrong)

```
svn merge -c -1234
```

Comment: Well what I am trying to do is figure out how to get Subversive to do the equivalent of these SVN commands that you linked me to. My development machine is running Windows/WAMP w/ Subclipse to interact with SVN so I am not exactly sure how to run SVN commands like that without using Subclipse or installing some other SVN client for Windows.

Comment: I gave up trying to do it with Subversive or TortoiseSVN or anything like that so I just ended up doing it through Ubuntu and the command line, it worked great using the info you gave me.